# UI blocked until a mouse event when invoking modal operator from another operator

Tags: python, interface, operator

When I invoke my modal operator from my other operator (invoked from a panel button) and the modal operator finishes, Blender's **UI is blocked until the mouse moves** (i.e. click on the same button has no effect unless the mouse is moved or clicked first).

Also, if the modal operator is invoked from a property update function then the UI is blocked until LMB click (moving or clicking other buttons has no effect).

However, **occasionally** blocking does **not** happen.

When looking at events in `modal()`, `event.type`/`event.value` for the first two events are:

- UI blocked - `MOUSMOVE`/`RELEASE`, `MOUSMOVE`/`RELEASE`
- UI not blocked - `MOUSMOVE`/`RELEASE`, `NONE`/`NOTHING`

An obvious question is why are there two `MOUSMOVE`/`RELEASE` events anyway ...

I am wondering why is this happening and even more **is there a way to avoid this UI blocking?**

(The reason I'm doing all this is in my [other question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79000/revert-mouse-pointer-cursor-back-to-default-after-a-modal-operation/).)

Example code:

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator

class TheModalOperator(Operator):
    bl_idname = "my.themodaloperator"
    bl_label = "TheModalOperator Operator"

    # counter of calls to modal()
    countmodal = 0

    def __del__(self):
        print("TheModalOperator End")

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        print("TheModalOperator invoke")
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def modal(self, context, event):
        self.countmodal += 1
        print("TheModalOperator modal", self.countmodal, event.type, event.value)
        if self.countmodal >= 2:
            print("---TheModalOperator modal finished")
            return {'FINISHED'}
        else:
            print("---TheModalOperator modal running")
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}       


class MyOperator(Operator):
    """This is my operator"""
    bl_idname = "my.operator"
    bl_label = "My Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        print("MyOperator execute")
        self.report({'INFO'}, "MyOperator executed")
        bpy.ops.my.themodaloperator('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
        return {'FINISHED'}


# button on the toolshelf
class MyTestPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "mytestpanel"
    bl_category = "My Stuff"
    bl_label = "My Test Panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
    bl_context = "objectmode"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column(align=True)
        col.label(text="This blocks UI until a mouse event:")
        col.operator("my.operator", text="Run my operator")

def register(): 
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

def unregister(): 
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Found solution: `modal` should return `PASS_THROUGH` (solves invoking from a property update function) **and** a timer (solves invoking from another operator). Will post this as an answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two fixes needed.

**1.** The `modal()` must return **`PASS_THROUGH`** instead of `RUNNING_MODAL`.
That allows Blender to process mouse events, however, fixes the problem **only** when invoked from **property update function**.

**2.** Using a **timer** instead of the counter.
I'm not clear why not just changing the counter limit to 3 does not work (that just requires another mouse event, i.e. need to move or click the mouse).
Nevertheless, the modal timer **does fix** the problem for invoking from **other operator** too.

**Fixed code:**

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator

class TheModalOperator(Operator):
    bl_idname = "my.themodaloperator"
    bl_label = "TheModalOperator Operator"

    timer = None

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        print("TheModalOperator invoke")
        self.timer = context.window_manager.event_timer_add(0.1, context.window)
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def modal(self, context, event):
        print("TheModalOperator modal", event.type, event.value)
        if event.type == 'TIMER':
            print("---TheModalOperator modal finished")
            context.window_manager.event_timer_remove(self.timer)
            return {'FINISHED'}
        else:
            print("---TheModalOperator modal pass-through")
            return {'PASS_THROUGH'}       


class MyOperator(Operator):
    """This is my operator"""
    bl_idname = "my.operator"
    bl_label = "My Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        print("MyOperator execute")
        self.report({'INFO'}, "MyOperator executed")
        bpy.ops.my.themodaloperator('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
        return {'FINISHED'}


# button on the toolshelf
class MyTestPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "mytestpanel"
    bl_category = "My Stuff"
    bl_label = "My Test Panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
    bl_context = "objectmode"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column(align=True)
        col.label(text="This blocks UI until a mouse event:")
        col.operator("my.operator", text="Run my operator")

def register(): 
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

def unregister(): 
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```